# Install spark and configure it

Tags: apache-spark, runtime-error, command-prompt

I installed spark and when type spark-shell in command Prompt, in the First write **is not recognized as an internal or external command** and after several lines, the spark is run. I want to see what is my problem?

```
C:\Users\Ramin>spark-shell
'#' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
20/08/27 03:30:30 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
20/08/27 03:30:30 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4041. Attempting port 4042.
Spark context Web UI available at http://DESKTOP-QQ9VRP2:4042
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1598482830954).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.6
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.12 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_261)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you’re running a windows machine?

Have you tried running `spark-shell.cmd` and seeing the same?

Comment: No, I run it in command prompt. I ran spark-shell in cmd.

Comment: Ok, I know commands such as ‘export’ are valid in unix based shells that why you see the “not recognised as internal or external command”. To be honest, I tend to run a unix based shell when working off a windows machine. But I would suggest double checking environment variables and set up. There are lots of detail guides for set up on windows machines

Comment: I removed the spark and reinstall it again and now it works truly without the above errors.
 now, I don't know what was my problem but the spark is work truly